# Create half hour intervals in location roster. Where only Open and Close times available SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that holds only the opening and closing times of a facility.  It holds this data in hours past midnight.  I would like to create a view that gives me every Half an Hour from Opening to closing by facility.

Code I am trying to use is as follows:

```
Select LR.CalendarDate, LR.Description, T.Time as Opentime, T1.Time as closetime, T2.Time
FROM    vw_ITS_LocationRosterWithLocation As LR
inner Join dbo.DateDimension As D  On cast (D.Date as date) = CAST (LR.CalendarDate as date)
inner join dbo.TimeDimension as T on T.MinuteFromMidnight = LR.StartTime
Inner Join dbo.TimeDimension as T1 on T1.MinuteFromMidnight = LR.EndTime
Cross join dbo.TimeDimension as T2
```

This Results in:

```
Date    Facility                Time Open    Time Closed Half Hour Intervals

2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  12:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  12:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  1:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  1:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  2:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  2:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  3:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  3:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  4:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  4:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  5:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  5:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  6:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  6:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  7:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  7:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  8:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  8:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  9:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  9:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  10:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  10:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  11:00:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  11:30:00 AM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  12:00:00 PM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  12:30:00 PM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  1:00:00 PM
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 8:00:00 AM  9:30:00 PM  1:30:00
```

I need to see:

```
Date            Facility        Time1   Time2
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 08:00am 08:30am
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 08:30am 09:00am
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 09:00am 09:30am
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 09:30am 10:00am
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 10:00am 10:30am
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 10:30am 11:00am
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 11:00am 11:30am
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 12:00pm 12:30pm
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 01:00pm 01:30pm
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 01:30pm 02:00pm
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 02:30pm 03:00pm
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 03:30pm 04:00pm
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 04:00pm 04:30pm
2018/06/03  LTCHS - Diamond - S 05:00pm 05:30pm
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need some details to be able to help you here. Specifically things like table definitions and sample data. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ I would solve this with a tally table.

Comment: Have you tried a WHERE clause?    Seems too obvious not to have tried it... what WHERE clause did you try and what happened?

Comment: Hi Sean,  Which table would you want the table definitions from and I have supplied sample data.  The first table is the data that is returned the second is what I would like to see.

Comment: Hi Tab,  I did try a WHERE clause for matching the starttime with the half hour.  It returned the starttime in the Half hour interval column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with a time interval table left joined to your data

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
    CalendarDate DATETIME,
    Description NVARCHAR(20),
    OpenTime DATETIME,
    CloseTime DATETIME
)


DECLARE @StartOfDay DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
DECLARE @EndofDay  DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1,@StartOfDay))

INSERT @Table SELECT GETDATE(),'T1',DATEADD(HOUR,5,@StartOfDay),DATEADD(HOUR,10,@StartOfDay)
INSERT @Table SELECT GETDATE(),'T2',DATEADD(HOUR,2,@StartOfDay),DATEADD(HOUR,4,@StartOfDay)
INSERT @Table SELECT GETDATE(),'T3',DATEADD(HOUR,5,@StartOfDay),DATEADD(HOUR,10,@StartOfDay)
INSERT @Table SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()),'T4',DATEADD(HOUR,5,@StartOfDay),DATEADD(HOUR,10,@StartOfDay)

DECLARE @MinuteSlice INT = 30


;WITH Times as 
( 
    SELECT
    TimeOfDay = @StartOfDay
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT TimeOfDay = DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinuteSlice, TimeOfDay) 
    FROM Times WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinuteSlice, TimeOfDay)  <= @EndofDay 
) 
SELECT 
    Temp.CalendarDate,
    Temp.Description,
    Time1 = Times.TimeOfDay,
    Time2 = DATEADD(MINUTE,@MinuteSlice, Times.TimeOfDay)
FROM 
    Times Times
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table Temp ON Times.TimeOfDay BETWEEN Temp.OpenTime AND Temp.CloseTime
WHERE
    NOT Temp.CalendarDate IS NULL
ORDER BY
    Description, 
    CalendarDate,
    Times.TimeOfDay
```

To transpose it into Time1 and Time2 you can add back the offset for each record.

To do this with your data you would need to replace  the @temp table with your data, minus the cross jloin which the left join takes care of.

```
SELECT 
    YourData.CalendarDate,
    YourData.Description,
    Time1 = CAST(Times.TimeOfDay AS TIME),
    Time2 = CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,@MinuteSlice, Times.TimeOfDay) AS TIME)
FROM 
    Times Times
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
        Select LR.CalendarDate, LR.Description, T.Time as Opentime, T1.Time as closetime, T2.Time
        FROM    vw_ITS_LocationRosterWithLocation As LR
        inner Join dbo.DateDimension As D  On cast (D.Date as date) = CAST (LR.CalendarDate as date)
        inner join dbo.TimeDimension as T on T.MinuteFromMidnight = LR.StartTime
        Inner Join dbo.TimeDimension as T1 on T1.MinuteFromMidnight = LR.EndTime
    )
    YourData ON CAST(Times.TimeOfDay AS TIME) BETWEEN CAST(YourData.OpenTime AS TIME) AND CAST(YourData.CloseTime AS TIME)    
WHERE
    NOT YourData.CalendarDate IS NULL
ORDER BY
    YourData.CalendarDate,
    YourData.Description, 
    Times.TimeOfDay
```

Comment: Forgive me I do not quite understand the 'I would do this with a time interval table left joined to your data'

Comment: Yes, the time cte is a calculation of a day cut up into slices, in your case 30 minute intervals. You need to left join your data to it in order to fill the gaps missing in your data (stat and end). I updated with a transpose for time1 and time2

Comment: Thank you.  I have a time table.  the main problem I have is getting that to join/match my data so that it looks like the sample data above.  Apologies if my understanding is not great, this is an area of SQL I am unfamiliar with.  I see you have Description, but I was unable to make my description from the data table go in.

Comment: Updated with a way to replace the test table with your data, however, I can not guarantee this will compile.

Comment: Thank you so much.  got it to get my data and set up half hour intervals.

Comment: I added a tidbit. I thought about and realized that would only permit values within the Times table, 1 day. In order to include multiple days you have to cast to TIMES to ignore dates for the data buckets. Sorry my shorthand got the best of me. The second query above truncates all dates to the time part so multiple dates will flow through. Improvements could be made by reduceing the CAST(AS TIME), however, time is a premium.